# intval() altera valores

Tags: php, request, int

Hoje estava fazendo uma aplicação web trabalhando com $_REQUEST.

Porem notei que ao realizar um UPDATE o valor saiu incorreto, e quando olhei as funções no php, foi aí o mais bizarro.

Perceba que o **intval()** quando recebe o request, muda totalmente o valor!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe me dizer porque isso acontece?

Comment: Pelo que me parece a sua variável é maior que o valor permitido para o tipo "int" em sistemas 32bits e  possivelmente quando você usa o intval() ele altera para o maior valor possível.

Comment: Mostra o código que gerou essa diferença

Comment: De uma olhada na doc: 

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.intval.php

Comment: Isso provavelmente está ocorrendo pois o valor máximo de `int` é `2147483647`*. Com o valor informado excede esse valor máximo, ele é reduzido.

Comment: @DiegoSchmidt  blza cara, valeu pela ajuda. Acredito que neste caso, por ser campos cadastráveis é importante usar um limitador ou algo do tipo, não sabia que existia isso!